# Meteor Testing : Mocha doesn't find all test files

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

I'm writing a test suite for a meteor application. I use `practicalmeteor:mocha` package to run the tests. Meteor tests are run using the commandline `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`.

My tests are placed in `$PROJECT/test/unit/client/` and `$PROJECT/test/unit/server/` . The server tests are being identified and run, whereas client tests aren't run. Any meteor devs who faced the same problem? I know mocha allows `mocha --recursive` but I'm not sure how to specify that in a `meteor test` command.

Comment: `mocha --recursive` . See http://mochajs.org/#usage

Comment: I did, just not sure how to combine it with meteor test command-line. `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`  is the cmd line I use.

Comment: @louis I'm not using mocha command directly, I use `meteor test` and pass mocha driver package.

Comment: @goKishore Edit your question with exactly what you tried, the setup you are using (what files are where), the results you are expecting and the results you are actually getting. Because the answer to "Is there a way to tell mocha to search recursively?" is exactly what Kairat said and what the answers on the other question go over.

Comment: @louis but I did tell I'm using meteor framework, and `meteor test` commandline to run the tests, which I think is not the same as `mocha --recursive`

Comment: @louis Yes, but I couldn't find a `mocha.opts` file in the project, and I don't know if I should just add one. There's nothing much about it on meteor [test guide](http://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#driver-packages)

Comment: I've reopened. I don't think either `--recursive` or `mocha.opts` are going to help.

Comment: thank you, I hope to hear from meteor developers

Answer (score 5):

If you mean that meteor does not even load your tests (try with an intentional syntax error in them to see if you get compilation errors) it might be that Meteor has configured itself to run tests only in some file. E.g in `package.json` I had

```
testModule: test/main.js
```

It seems that this causes Meteor to not follow its documented rules for finding tests and only loads this module.

Try removing this configuration to get default behaviour, or point it to your main test module (which then needs to pull in other tests).

NB. I think you should use `meteortesting:mocha` nowadays...

Comment: Thanks for this, I found that I had the same issue and deleting `"testModule": "tests/main.js` from package.json did the trick!